# Google Apps Script: Message Content As Is submitted (Form Submission Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Please excuse me for my lack of understanding of the process of Google apps. I recently figured out how to send email containing data from Google Form submission to myself/others. The script I have is working great, however, I have ran into an issue where the content of the message that the script sends is in a linear format. For example, the user enters two sentences with a line separating them, and all I see is a long linear text.

It would help me greatly if anyone knows how to receive Form submission data in "As-Is" form submitted by the user. Please take a look at my code to see if there is any way to implement such a thing in Google Scripts.

```
function sendFormByEmail(e)  {    
  var email = "xxxxx@xxxx.com";  
  var subject1 = "Approval Required Case # ";
  var subject2 = " submitted by: ";

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  

  var message2 = "";
  var message1 = "";
  var replyemail = "";
  for(var i in headers)
    message2 += "<u><b>" + headers[i] + "</b></u> : " + e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "<br><br>" + "\n\n"; 
    message1 += "<b><font color ='blue'><big> Hi XXXX, </big></font></b>" + "<br><br>" + "Could you please approve the below? " + "<br><br>";
    replyemail = e.namedValues['Username'].toString();
  Logger.log(message);  

  subject=subject1 + e.namedValues['Case Number'].toString() + subject2 + e.namedValues['Username'].toString();
  var message = message1 + message2;

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,message,{name: "Approval Submission: Review",replyTo: replyemail, cc: "" ,'htmlBody':message,}); 
}
```

Again,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically, you want to preserve the newlines in your data?

Comment: I think so because currently my code fetches headers from spreadsheet + data users submitted to correlating fields in the Google Form. My concern is when people submit two paragraphs (with space in between) in specfic field in the form, the email notification shows the two paragraphs submitted by user behind their correlating header in long linear format with no separation between them. I basically want to see the data as user submitted them ( with space between paragraphs).

Comment: Is this really not doable by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For: Anybody interested..**

I figured out how to achieve the desired effect stated in my original question. How..?

Very simple addition: `.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g','<br /v>')` after my content string.

*Check out the code below*

```
    message2 += "<u><b>" + headers[i] + "</b></u> : " + e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString().replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />') 
+ "<br><br>" + "\n\n";
```

Best of luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript replace method to change all the newline characters with `<br>`

```
message = message.replace("\n", "<br>");
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,message,{name: "Approval Submission: Review",replyTo: replyemail, cc: "" ,'htmlBody':message});
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I will try your suggestion tomorrow! I will update whether or not it works. It could drastically improve user experience as well as help others in need! :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The issue is still present in the notification email.